# Regex capture group multiple times and other groups

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to make a regex expression which capture multiple groups of data.

Here is some data example :

```
sampledata=X
B : xyz=1 FAB1_1=03 FAB2_1=01
A : xyz=1 FAB1_1=03 FAB2_1=01
```

I need to capture the `X` which should appear one time, and `FAB1_1=03`, `FAB2_1=01`, ... All the strings which starts with `FAB`.

So, I could capture all "FAB" like this :

```
/(FAB[0-9]_[0-9]=[0-9]*)/sg
```

But I could not include the capture of `X` using this expression :

```
/sampledata=(?<samplegroup>[0-9A-Z]).*(FAB[0-9]_[0-9]=[0-9]*)/sg
```

This regex only return one group with `X` and the last match of group of "FAB".

Comment: Something like [`(?:sampledata=(\S+)|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!FAB[0-9]_[0-9]=).)*(FAB[0-9]_[0-9])=([0-9]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/gA5zE6/1)?

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, Exactly ! Thanks, I don't really understand your expression, but it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:sampledata=(\S+)|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!FAB[0-9]_[0-9]=).)*(FAB[0-9]_[0-9])=([0-9]*)‌​
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA5zE6/1)

The regex is based on the `\G` operator that matches either the start of string or *the end of the previous successful match*. We restrict it to match only in the latter case with a negative lookahead `(?!^)`.

So:

- `(?:sampledata=(\S+)|(?!^)\G)` - match a literal `sampledata=` and then match and capture into Group 1 one or more non-whitespace symbols -OR- match the end of the previous successful match
- `(?:(?!FAB[0-9]_[0-9]=).)*` - match any text that is not `FABn_n=` (this is a [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed))
- `(FAB[0-9]_[0-9])`  - Capture group 2, matching and capturing `FAB` followed with a digit, then a `_`, and one more digit
- `=` - literal `=`
- `([0-9]*)‌​` - Capture group 3, matching and capturing zero or more digits

**If you have 1 `sampledata=` block**, you can safely *unroll* the tempered greedy token ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA5zE6/3)) as

```
(?:sampledata=(\S+)|(?!^)\G)[^F]*(?:F(?!FAB[0-9]_[0-9]=)[^F]*)*?(FAB[0-9]_[0-9])=([0-9]*)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That way, the expression will be more efficient.

**If you have several `sampledata` blocks**, enhance the tempered greedy token:

```
(?:sampledata=(\S+)|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!sampledata=|FAB[0-9]_[0-9]=).)*(FAB[0-9]_[0-9])=([0-9]*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA5zE6/2)

Comment: Just a note: unrolled regex pattern does not require `/s` modifier, tempered greedy token does.